# .net dllimport DllNotFoundException but the dll is indeed there.

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I'm using `DllImport` in my c# application. It works fine on my windows 7 machine, but on a windows 8 it gives the DllNotFoundException.

A customer of our has the same issue on his windows 7 machine.

I even hacked the code just to test it out by supplying the absolute path like so

```
[DllImport("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyApp\\A.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void foo(string filename, MulticastDelegate callback);
```

But it still gives the DllNotFoundException at the path C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\A.dll ....

But the DLL is indeed there!!! ....

Comment: on 32bit machines, the path to programfiles is `c:\program files\ ` **not** `c:\program files (x86)\ `

Comment: I know it was just a test on my 64 bit windows 8 machine to see if the absolute path would resolve the issue but it doesn't.

Comment: Have you checked file / directory permissions?  Ie user account its running as can actually see and read the file?

Comment: Also any InnerException / other details?

Comment: If the DLL is 32-bit, set Target = x86 for the application exe.

Answer (score 0):

Path has spaces, so my guess is using:

```
[DllImport("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyApp\\A.dll\"", ...]
```